# Isoperimetric problem.

Tags: geometry

**Introduction.**

The isoperimetric problem is to determine a plane figure of the largest possible area whose boundary has a specified length ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)).

---

I know several ways to solve this problem and I do *not* ask about any of them. I want to ask about my own solution which I describe below.
What do you think is it valid?

**Solution**

It is quite obvious that figure must be *convex*
in order to bound the largest area.

Suppose we have convex figure $\Phi$. Without
loss of generality we can assume that length of
$\Phi$ is equal to 1, so $l = 1$. Next step is 
to draw a straight line (call it $L_1$) that intersects $\Phi$
so points of intersections, say, $p_1$ and $p_2$
are split $\partial\Phi$ into two curves, say, $l_1$ and $l_2$ which have *equal* length.
$L_1$ splits $\Phi$ into two 
figures, say, $\Phi'$ and $\Phi''$. Now the following algorithm should be executed:

**Algorithm**

1. If $S(\Phi')\geq S(\Phi'')$ then substitute ∂Φ″ with the reflection of ∂Φ′ around the line dividing Φ″ from Φ′.
    Else vice-versa.
2. Choose another line $L_i$ which is do the same job as the line $L_{i-1}$.
3. Return to step 1.

Where $S(\Phi)$ is area bounded by $\Phi$. It requires to note that $L_i$ can be chosen in the following way: every iteration point $p_1$  shifts along $\partial \Phi$ by $1/\sqrt{2}$. The second point $p_2$ then appear in order to fulfill the above condition.

It is obvious that $\Delta(S(\Phi))\geq 0$ after
each iteration of the above algorithm. Also obvious that if initial figure was a circle then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{S(\Phi_0) - S(\Phi_n)} = 0.$$

BUT. It is not obvious for me the opposite statement:
$$\forall \Phi_0: \lim_{n\to\infty}{\Phi_n} = \mathrm{Circle}.$$

Comment: You are imitating Steiner simmetrization, but your argument is very much incomplete.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, It seems you are right. Thank you.

Comment: It is an interesting approach, but it does not really work. If the initial curve is an ellipse, every chord bisecting the perimeter also bisects the area, but the area of an ellipse can be increased without affecting the perimeter, since the perimeter of an ellipse is given by the AGM mean.

Comment: I do not understand  your logic. Could you explain what do you mean in more details.

Comment: I haven't a proof of your last statement, but I tried your algorithm with Mathematica, starting from a square, and I got a nice circle.

Comment: To proof you would check all convex closed curves;) BTW could you post here some of your iterations.

Comment: I'll certainly do that later, now I'm busy. Let me add that you simply wrote "If S(Φ′)≥S(Φ″) then change ∂Φ″ to ∂Φ′ ", which is too vague. In my algorithm, I substituted ∂Φ″ with the reflection of ∂Φ′ around the line dividing Φ″ from Φ′.   
By the way: I also tried a version of your algorithm, where at each step the half with LOWER area is taken. The result is quite surprising.

Comment: I have edited formulation. Your second result is intriguing. Wait for it.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer: I'm just showing some results I obtained with Mathematica from the algorithm described above.

Starting from a square, one readily ends with a circle (50 iterations are shown):
[image]

Starting from a rectangle (base : height = 100 : 1) one gets a circle again (50 iterations are shown). Notice that at a concave polygon might arise in the process, in which case one of its halves could be a self-intersecting polygon.

[image]

To prove that the iteration always tends to a circle, one could argue as follows:

1) polygon area is a not decreasing and bounded sequence, so it must tend to a limit;

2) the limiting figure must be reflection symmetric across any line dividing its perimeter into two equal pieces, but only a circle possesses such a symmetry.

This reasoning is flawed: area tends to a limit, but we don't know that there is a single shape corresponding to that limiting value. There could be, for instance, two or more limiting figures, such that applying the algorithm to one of them one gets another one. I found an example of that in the "minimum" algorithm, see below.

Just for fun, I also considered a "minimum" algorithm, where at each step one reflects the polygon having lower area, instead of the larger one. I was quite surprised when I saw that, starting with a square, a circle would apparently still be the limiting shape (200 iterations are shown):

[image]

On closer inspection, however, I realized it is not a "smooth" circle, because it has a jagged perimeter (so I presume the limiting shape could be some kind of fractal).

Starting with a rectangle I got another strange limiting behaviour: not a single shape, but two polygons of different area, with one of them transforming into a rotated copy of the other (200 iterations are shown):

[image]

There is a caveat: the area for a self-intersecting polygon can be defined in several ways. I used a formula which counts the different loops with different sign, according to their chirality. Using a different definition could lead to different results.

Comment: WOW. Amazing. Thanks a lot for this. BTW. My arguments were the same as yours when I started to solve the isoperimetric problem but then, wait a minute, who said that algorithm leads us to maximum area. It can be (maybe it cannot be) that starting with one figure all process turned to the loop. I think you said the same in other words. P.S. About ''Minimum'' algorithm. It deserves separate question.