# What property is related to this?

Tags: geometry

This question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093718/isoperimetric-problem/2099023#2099023) question.

---

### Description

Let us to start with any *convex* figure. without loss of generality we may assume that 
length of its perimeter is equal to 1. Then let's execute the following algorithm:

1. Choose line $L$ which goes through point $p_0$ on $\partial \Phi$ and divides $\Phi$ into two subfigures $\Phi'$ and $\Phi''$ such that $|\partial \Phi'| = |\partial \Phi''|$.
   If $S(Φ′)\leq S(Φ″)$ then substitute $∂Φ″$ with the reflection of $∂Φ′$ around the $L$.
     Else vice-versa.
   We get other figure $\chi$. Assign $\Phi = \chi$
2. Substitute $p_0$ with other point $p_0'$ 
   which away from $p_0$ by $1/\sqrt{2}$ along $\partial \Phi$. Assign $p_0 = p_0'$
3. Return to step 1.

Starting with a square @Aretino obtained this:[image: min]
So what property is related to this? Something like *find convex closed curve possessed given 
length with the smallest area* does not work, obviously.

---

Not every starting figures leads to this jagged circle. For example, rectangle does not.

Comment: I am the author;)

Comment: oops!  Well, then, it would be silly to ask yourself a question! :-)